# How to write nested query in jooq with SUM operation from the subquery output?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, subquery, jooq

Let's say I want to find out the sum of one of the table from the nested subquery. Let's take the subquery given below. How to calculate the status count using `DSL.sum(when(condition))`

```
Table<Record4<Integer, Integer, String, String>> orgWiseCountTable = dsl.select(
                         field("master_id", Integer.class).as(masterId),
                         field("transaction_id", Integer.class).as(transactionId),
                         field("api_status", String.class).as(status),
                         field("Organisations.organisation_name",String.class).as(organisationName)
            )
                    .from(TestTable)

                    .leftJoin(Organisations)

                    .on(TestTable.organsiationId.eq(Organisations.organsiationId)

                    .where(condition)

                    .groupBy(TestTable.master_id).asTable("orgWiseCount");
```

Using the above Table record how can we calculate the sum of api_status depending on whether or not the value is **COMPLETED** or not.

Trying the below approach but it isn't working.

```
transactions = dsl.select(
                    orgWiseCountTable.field(organisationName).as("OrganisationName"),
                    orgWiseCountTable.field("SUM(status = 'COMPLETED')").as(
                                    "SuccessCount"),
                    orgWiseCountTable.field("SUM(kyc_api_transaction_master.api_status <> 'COMPLETED')").as(
                                    "FailureCount"),
                    orgWiseCountTable.field(totalCount).as("TotalCount")
                    )

                    .from(orgWiseCountTable)
                    .fetch()
                    .into(Count.class);
```

Getting Null pointer exception while calculating sum. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you show the SQL query that you'd like to get as output? Also, from your example, I don't see why you'd create a subquery like that. The outer query doesn't do anything other than aggregating, so the subquery can be inlined. Maybe, your actual query does a bit more?

Comment: Please refer to the sample query here [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75547771/how-to-write-nested-sql-query-in-jooq-with-sum-operation-in-select). Also how can we aggregate the the values from the inner query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using derived tables

As I [answered to your follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75554469/521799), I don't think you really need the derived table. You'll simplify your life greatly, if you just remove it.

### Dereferencing columns from a derived table

If your actual query is more complex than the one you've presented here, you'll have to dereference columns from your derived table like this:

```java
// Dereference first:
Field<String> status = orgWiseCountTable.field("status", String.class);

// Alternatively, dereference using generaetd code for added convenience:
Field<String> status = orgWiseCountTable.field(THE_TABLE.STATUS);

// Then use in expressions:
DSL.count().filterWhere(status.eq("Completed")).as("SuccessCount");
```

### Aggregate filter clause

Note, I'm using [`FILTER`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/aggregate-filter/) instead, which is a standard SQL feature. This will be a bit more convenient to write in jOOQ, than using the MySQL specific approach of mapping booleans to integers in order to sum them. `A.eq(B)` is a `Condition` in jOOQ, which extends `Field<Boolean>`, and you cannot really sum booleans.

### Code generation

This isn't necessary relevant to your question, but I highly recommend you [start using jOOQ's code generator](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/). A lot of features will be unlocked by that, and your queries will be much simpler to write.

Comment: Still getting Null Pointer Exception even though I have dereferenced the column.

`Field<String> APISTATUS = orgWiseCountTable.field("status", String.class);
transactions =dsl.select(orgWiseCountTable.field(organisationName).as("OrganisationName")                    orgWiseCountTable.field(DSL.count().filterWhere(APISTATUS.eq("COMPLETED")).as("SuccessCount")), orgWiseCountTable.field(DSL.count().filterWhere(APISTATUS.notEqual("COMPLETED")).as("FailureCount")),orgWiseCountTable.field(totalCount).as("TotalCount")).from(orgWiseCountTable).fetch().into(OrganisationWiseCount.class);`

Comment: Getting error in the select query. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Well, is there a `"status"` column in your derived table or not? (Note: dereferencing iss case sensitive)